# How to change canvas url by php script in facebook web apps

Tags: php, facebook-canvas

I am using facebook web apps and I see that I can change canvas URL only by going through developer section of facebook API. Is there anyway that I can update or change canvas URL by PHP script as I can change some other setting like permission for facebook apps.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I am aware.

You can however pass parameters to the canvas URL, and then include other PHP scripts depending on the parameter passed.

```
$action = "";

if (isset($_REQUEST['action]))
    {
        $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
    }

switch ($action) {
case "football":
      require_once("football.php");
      break;
case "tennis":
      require_once("tennis.php");
      break;
default:
      require_once("skydiving.php"); 
}
```